# Delphi "for ... to" statement runs from end value to start value

Tags: delphi, for-loop

I'm writing a simple app in Embarcadero Delphi 2010. A simple code with two cycles:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a:array [0..255] of integer;
i:integer;
k,q:integer;
begin
k:=0;
for I := 0 to 255 do
 begin
    a[i]:=i;
 end;

for I := 0 to 255 do
 begin
    q:= a[i];
    k:=k+q;
 end;
Label1.Caption:=inttostr(k);
end;
```

According to Watch List, in second cycle variable "i" starts from value 256 and going to 0 (256, 255, 254, ..., 0), but array's elements is correct (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). Variable "i" declared only locally, no global variables.
Why does this happens? Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: Side note: do not use *magic numbers*: `for i := 0 to Length(a) do`

Comment: Just a strange behavior test, not a production code. Length(a) works this way, too.

Comment: A little bit of googling should have given heaps of hits telling you it's an optimization by the Delphi compiler which only is applied if it doesn't alter the meaning of your code.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This is wrong code: `for i := 0 to Length(a) do`. Length of `a` is 256, loop will hit RangeCheckError. Proper code should be `for i := 0 to High(a) do`

Comment: @KromStern: No, proper use should be for i:=low(a) to high(a)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is because of compiler optimization. The long answer is:

In your `Pascal` code, the integer `I` has two (actually three) purposes. First, it is the loops *control variable* (or loop counter), that is, it controls how many times the loop is run. Secondly, it acts as index to the array `a`. And in the first loop it also acts as the value assigned to the array elements. When compiled to machine code, these roles are handled by different registers.

If optimization is set in compiler settings, the compiler creates code that decrements the control variable from a start value down towards zero, *if it can do so, without changing the end result*. This it does, because a comparison against a non-zero value can be avoided, thus being faster.

In following disassembly of the **first loop**, you can see that the roles of variable `I` are handled as:

- Register `eax` acts as loop control variable *and value* to be
  assigned to array elements
- Register `edx` is pointer to array element (incremented with 4
  (bytes) per turn)

disassembly:

```
Unit25.pas.34: for I := 0 to 255 do
005DB695 33C0             xor eax,eax             // init
005DB697 8D9500FCFFFF     lea edx,[ebp-$00000400]
Unit25.pas.36: a[i]:=i;
005DB69D 8902             mov [edx],eax           // value assignment
Unit25.pas.37: end;
005DB69F 40               inc eax                 // prepare for next turn
005DB6A0 83C204           add edx,$04             // same
Unit25.pas.34: for I := 0 to 255 do
005DB6A3 3D00010000       cmp eax,$00000100       // comparison with end of loop
005DB6A8 75F3             jnz $005db69d           // if not, run next turn
```

Since `eax` has two roles, it must count upward. Note that it requires three commands for each loop to manage the loop counting: `inc eax`, `cmp eax, $00000100` and `jnz $005db69d`.

In the disassembly of the **second loop**, the roles of variable `I` are handled similarily as in the first loop, except `I` is not assigned to the elements. Therefore the loop control only acts as a loop counter and can be run downward.

- Register `eax` is loop control variable
- Register `edx` is pointer to array element (incremented with 4
  (bytes) per turn)

disassembly:

```
Unit25.pas.39: for I := 0 to 255 do
005DB6AA B800010000       mov eax,$00000100       // init loop counter
005DB6AF 8D9500FCFFFF     lea edx,[ebp-$00000400]
Unit25.pas.41: q:= a[i];
005DB6B5 8B0A             mov ecx,[edx]
Unit25.pas.42: k:=k+q;
005DB6B7 03D9             add ebx,ecx
Unit25.pas.43: end;
005DB6B9 83C204           add edx,$04    // prepare for next turn
Unit25.pas.39: for I := 0 to 255 do
005DB6BC 48               dec eax        // decrement loop counter, includes intrinsic comparison with 0
005DB6BD 75F6             jnz $005db6b5  // jnz = jump if not zero
```

Note that in this case only two commands are needed to manage loop counting: `dec eax` and `jnz $005db6b5`.

In Delphi XE7, in the Watches window, variable `I` is shown during the first loop as incrementing values but during the second loop as `E2171 Variable 'i' inaccessible here due to optimization`. In earlier versions I recall it was showing decrementing values which I believe you see.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer!

Answer (score 8):

I have copied your exact code and when I ran it the variable "i" counts normally in both for cycles. Have you ran the second cycle step by step? The "i" is really 256 at the start of the second cycle because of the first one but as soon as the second cycle starts "i" becomes 0 and it counts normally to 255.

I don't see how or why would it count from 256 to 0?

**UPDATE:**
I haven't even thought of this, but here's your explanation I belive: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/45/418603.html

> " It's a compiler optimization - you're not using "I" inside your loop
>   hence  compiler thought of a better way to count . Your loop count
>   will still be  accurate..."

Comment: In Delphi XE4 all works fine. Noticed it only in Delphi 2010. The "i" is 256 at first interation, not only at the start, 255 at second interation,  254 at third and so on... But it's only in Watch List. If I try to write "i" in some output, everything occasionally wents to normal order: 0, 1, 2, .... "I don't see how or why would it count from 256 to 0?" - me too, this is what the question about =)

Comment: I decided to simply google your question and found the reason for it, I updated my answer now. I myself didn't know about this compiler optimization till now.

Comment: Tried to google it, but always come on "for ...  downto" syntax help. Thanks a lot =)