# Why loop While with for inside doen't work?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I'm trying to break out of the while loop by changing the `auxboolean` variable inside the for loop but it doesn't work.  The for loop doesn't exit when `auxboolean` is set to `false`.  Why?

Also, the for loop seems to start with `i` having value 9 and counts backwards.  Why?

```
auxboolean:= true;
    while auxboolean do
    begin
      for i := 0 to 8  do
      begin
       auxboolean:=false;
      end;
    end;
```

When debugging you can see that the first value for `i` is 9 and it then counts down :

[image: Debug]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you would like to achieve here and what does "but doesn't work" mean? What doesn't work?

Comment: sorry, I tried to explaind with the pictures and now write the explain

Comment: Borland Developer 2006 @J...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like that:

```
begin
  auxboolean:=true;

  for i := 0 to 8 do
    begin
      Writeln(i);

      auxboolean:=false;

      if not auxboolean then break;
    end;

  Writeln('End of the program...');
  Readln;
end.
```

You don't have to use the while loop, instead of it see the break statement.

Comment: I tried with Exit and abort, but finish all my function. With break work, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The condition for the `while` loop to continue is `auxboolean = true`.

The check for `auxboolean = true` is performed only when the code returns to the `while` statement. What happens to `auxboolean` inside the loop has no effect before that check.

The condition for the `for` loop to continue is that the loop control variable `i` is 0..8.

The check for `i` happens equally once per loop, but has no effect on the outer `while` loop. You can use `break` to exit the for loop.

---

edit:

The peculiarity with the `for` loop starting from 9 and counting down is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478474/2292722)

I'm not sure whether this is still the case in recent releases of Delphi. I think it is, but the debugger does not show decreasing counter values.

Comment: Think that immediately the value of loop why change finish, I came from Java maybe is for that or forget stuff. Thanks for the new knowledge

Comment: @MiguelJumping: No, this works the same way in all imperative programming languages, including Java.

Comment: Ok, this evening I go to study the basics again

Comment: Miguel, did you note the edit I made and the link to another answer regarding the `for` loop counter.

Comment: Thanks Tom,  think this happen to my borland that today waking up with the left foot.